# How to read the body of the request in Azure App Service?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift2, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create an EasyAPI in Azure App Service (migrated from Azure Mobiles Services). The message is sent from an iOS app using the following command in swift:

```
    let query: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["name": theName]
    let param: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["collectionName": theCollectionName, "query": query]

    AOAppDelegate.client!.invokeAPI("FMDataAPI", body: param, HTTPMethod: "POST", parameters: nil, headers: nil, completion: {(objects, httpResponse, error) in

       if error == nil {

          //Process response

       } else {
          print(error!.userInfo)
       }
    })
```

In the API I have the following Javascript code within the EasyAPI MyEasyAPI:

```
module.exports = {
"post": function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("---------------------------------------")
    console.log(req.body)
},
```

But body stays undefined.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

GA

Comment: Take out the req.app.use lines and references to bodyParser, as the Mobile App service will already have included that middleware for you. If you are still having problems, how about updating your question with the current code using POST?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I edit my question with the new code I tried. I removed the req.app.use lines and I replaced the get with the post and the req.body is still undefined. Is it the body property the one I need to use? The parameters come within req.query, but req.body doesn't seem to contain anything at all. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, req.body should have the body content in the server script. I suspect the client doesn't like the nested dictionary you're passing to invokeAPI. Try removing the query dictionary and define the param dictionary with all the parameters: `let param: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["collectionName": theCollectionName, "name": theName]`

Comment: That's a good idea. I need the nested dictionary though. There is another signature of this method that sends a NSData instead of AnyObject. I can serialise the Json and sending it as data. Will req.body deserialise it automatically as well?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.

Comment: Hi there.It didn't work. I pulled the code of the Azure framework for iOS from github and checked the invokeAPI method and it looks fine. The body is included in the http request in both versions of the method. I created an issue in github and they suggested to add the content-type "application/json" in the header, but it doesn't make any difference either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions.
I reported an issue in the github project of the Azure Mobile Apps iOS client and they suggested that the problem could be in the version of the node package azure-mobile-apps and this was the case.

The azure-mobile-apps package was in version 2.0.0. After I updated to 2.1.0 req.body started to receive data.

Here you have the link to the [Gihub issue discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client/issues/70#issuecomment-212330334).

Thanks again for your suggestions.

GA

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the app before the easy API gets called. By the time you are adding the middleware, it's too late.  Fortunately, bodyparser is already implemented for you.  Note that generally, you need to be doing something that expects a body - like a POST - to do this.

Since this is a migrated mobile service, you need to follow the instructions for mobile services - things that are documented for App Service are generally only available for upgraded sites (that is, sites running on App Service that have not been migrated).

Good news is that we have some help there if you need it.  Check out the node module: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node-compatibility for more information.

Comment: Hi,Sorry, I used the wrong term. The site has been upgraded. All the code in both ends are in the last release. Do you have an example on how to implemente the body parser? I am implementing a POST method. I copied with get method here by mistake,

Comment: I edit my question with a few changed I did to the code, but req.body is still undefined. Is req.body the right property? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar use case with my custom API and fetched the parameter data via the query statement - I used a GET call, but that shouldn't make any difference here:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function (req, res, next) {
        var param = req.query.completed;
        console.log(param);
    }
};
```

The call with the attached parameter dictionary on the iOS side looked as follows:

```
[self.client invokeAPI:@"resetMyItems"
                  body:nil
            HTTPMethod:@"GET"
            parameters:@{@"completed": @(self.completed)}
               headers:nil
            completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Got answer from my own API: %@", result);
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Something went wrong with POST api call: %@", error);
                }
            }
 ];
```

I searched quite a long time to find out, that the parameter you attach on your API call on the iOS side is called EXACTLY the same as on the query statement on your request.

Hope that helps :)